# How to make user profile picture appear instantly without loading in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have this side menu : https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF5Ko.jpg in an app with user's profile picture. When i open this it loads the default picture first even tho the user profile is already saved. Everytime the drawer opens, for a split second the default picture appears before the user profile picture. How can i get rid of this?
This is the code

```
saveimageside(path) async {
    SharedPreferences saveimageside = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    saveimageside.setString("imagePathside", path);
  }

  loadimageside() async {
    SharedPreferences saveimageside = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      profileimage = saveimageside.getString("imagePath").toString();
    });
  }
```

Profile image code:

```
             profileimage != null
                                  ? CircleAvatar(
                                      backgroundImage:
                                          
                                     FileImage(File(profileimage)),
                                      radius:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                              0.05,
                                    )
                                  : CircleAvatar(
                                      backgroundImage: const AssetImage(
                                          'assets/profile.png'),
                                      radius:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                              0.05,
                                    )
```

Comment: It just takes few milisec to load the data from SharedPreferences , you can also use hive in this case.

Answer (score 0):

its behaving like this maybe becuase '*profileimage*' isn't waiting for *saveimageside.getString("imagePath").toString()* to return value.

**try adding *await* in your code like this:**

```
profileimage =await saveimageside.getString("imagePath").toString();
```

hope this solves it.

Comment: to add await, i had to make setState async but then the default image is being shown for more time than before..

Comment: have you tried using flag like isLoading? and checking it before showing any image ?      like setting it true while fetching image and checking it if its true then show circularProgressbar and if its false (when fetching is done) then show image